# GAE + Cloud SQL - How to understand different Tiers

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing) Google offers different tiers of their google-cloud-sql

I dont understand when someone will need to upgrade the very basic d0 tier.

My questions are:

1) If you are connecting GAE to cloud-sql, will the sql concurrent connections limit the scalability of your GAE app to 250 concurrent requests? I mean, will GAE create a new connection to cloud-sql on every request?

1bis) Can a very requested GAE app use only one sql connection?

2) Could you give some case-scenarios when Dx may be recomendable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what i dont understand is when someone will need to upgrade the very
>   basic d0 tier.

When its performance proves insufficient for your workload (number and size of queries) resulting in too-slow responses to user queries (or back-end tasks).  https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/instance-info explains how to view all the info about a given Cloud SQL instance.

> 1) if you are connecting GAE to cloud-sql, will the sql concurrent
>   connections limit the scalability of your GAE app to 250 concurrent
>   requests ? i mean, will GAE create a new connection to cloud-sql on
>   every request ?

Actually, **your PHP code** will do that, e.g with a call such as

```
$sql = new mysqli( ... etc, etc
```

if and when it needs a Cloud SQL connection to serve a request.  I do not believe there can be any way to share a single connection among different servers (and multiple concurrent requests are typically served by different servers -- although if your code is threadsafe a single server might be responding to a few requests concurrently, and I guess you **could** try to share a single connection among threads with locking, though that might impact latency and would only give you a small amount of connection-reuse anyway).

> 1bis) can a very requested GAE app use only one sql connection ?

A "very requested GAE app" is no doubt going to be using multiple servers at once, and there is no way separate servers can share 1 mySql connection.

> 2) could you give some case-scenarios when Dx may be recomendable ?

You'll just want larger instances in proportion to how big/demanding your workload is -- larger databases and indices, big/heavy requests including ones processing or returning lots of data, many concurrent requests, heavy background "data mining" going on at the same time, and so forth.

I would recommend using the calculator at https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/ -- click on the Cloud SQL icon if that's specifically what you want to explore -- to determine expected monthly costs for an instance.

As for the performance you can expect in return, that's so totally dependent on your data, indices, workloads, &c, that there's really no shortcut for it: rather, I recommend building a minimal meaningful sample of **your** app's needs and a stress-load test for it, tune it first on a local MySQL installation, then deploy experimentally to Cloud SQL in different configurations to measure the effects.

Once you've gone to the trouble of building and calibrating such benchmarks, you may of course also want to try out other competing providers of "mysql in the cloud" services, to know for sure exactly what performance you're getting for your money -- I'm unfortunately not very knowledgeable about what all is available on the market, but my key message is to use **your own** benchmarks, built to be meaningful for **your** app, rather than relying on "canned" benchmarks...

Comment: Great answer Alex, thank you very much for taking your valuable time for this. Just for resuming: one can say that if d0 cloud-sql provides 250 concurrent connections, in the best-case scanario your gae-app will be able to handle at maximum such number, am i right ?

Comment: @user2260245, if you need to connect to MySQL to serve **every** request, yes.  Depending on your app, you may be able to stash away in memcache and/or into the datastore some data enabling you to serve **some** requests straight out of such "cached" data, w/o MySQL connection -- that might well leverage up your ability to serve concurrent requests **and** reduce latency for serving some requests, a big win-win; but, the usefulness of this key technique is too dependent on your specific app's details, for me to be able to offer any further help on this!